# How to emit result in Tekton with python script?

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, tekton

I my Tekton pipeline I want to emit a result so that `$(results.myresult)` can be used in the next pipeline task. The code looks like this:

```
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: Task
  name: foo
  namespace: bar
...
spec:
  results:
    - name: myresult
  script: |
    #!/usr/bin/env bash 
    # do some meaningful stuff here before emitting the result
    myvar="foobar"
    printf $(params.myvar) | tee $(results.myresult)
```

However, I want to use python instead of a bash script. How can I emit the result variable?
I guess I'd have to use something like this in python:

```
var myvar = "foobar"
sys.stdout.write(myvar)
```

But how can I write this into $(results.myresult) and mimic the combination of pipe and `tee` from Linux in python?

Comment: I don't understand your (allegedly working) bash script. You assign a variable named `myvar`, but you never actually use it anywhere. The first step you are doing instead is to run a program named `params.myvar`. You make `printf` to use the stdout of this program for feeding the pipe. This means you could equally well have written `params.myvar | tee ...`.  If you want to discuss this problem, start with a meaningful bash script - then we can think of how to translate this to Python.

Comment: You don't "mimic the pipe operation", you just write the output to both the desired output file and stdout. You do what `| tee` does, in other words.

Comment: @user1934428 we're talking about a tekton pipeline task. What I actually do is described here: https://tekton.dev/docs/pipelines/pipelines/#emitting-results-from-a-pipeline

Comment: @kindall I found this https://shallowsky.com/blog/programming/python-tee.html. I'll try it out and report back whether it helped.

Comment: After your edit, your question becomes more clear, and I retracted the closing vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works as well.

```
script: |
  #!/usr/bin/env python3

  with open('$(results.myresult.path)', 'w') as f:
      f.write('myresult')
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would look at .... your `sys.stdout.write` kind of suggests you are writing stuff ... to stdout. While you mean to write this to your RESULTS (`$(results.myresult)`).

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution! This is how a working example would look like using python:

```
script: |
  #!/usr/bin/python3
  import subprocess
  with open('$(results.myresult.path)', 'w') as f:
      result = subprocess.run(['printf', 'This is a test!'], stdout=f)
  print(result.stdout)
```